# python path for setting Django app

Tags: python, django, django-apps

Believe me or not but after searching the web for half an hour I couldn't find the answer:
How to install django app (ex. django-profile) to the specific python path?

The problem is I installed it with pip but it was installed on the "global" path. I don't want it. I want it to be installed in /home/usr/Dev/lib folder where my project lives.

Could you help me? Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: Yulia, I recommend you go through your previous questions and mark them answered (click the checkbox next to the post) as you've given confirmation that the answer is good on many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the author of pip himself:

[Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/pip-how-do-i-install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory)

```
PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/folder
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" django-profile
```

This would install `django-profile` in  `/path/to/folder/lib/pythonX/site-packages`

Answer (score 2):

With [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) you can customize where the django apps and python packages are installed.