# How to backup python dependencies or modules already installed

Tags: python, dependencies, backup

i have installed many python modules plugins and libraries in my centos system.
Now i don't want to install each thing again on separate computers.

Is there any way i can make the package like rpm or any other thing so that when i install in in new location all the modules, dependencies also gets installed and everytime i install new thing i can update the install package

Answer (score 10):

If you have installed the packages with pip (an improved easy_install), you can just do `pip freeze > my-reqs.txt` to get a list and versions of the installed packages. There is also some option to install using the reqs file:

```bash
pip install -r my-reqs.txt
```

`Pip` is meant to companion `virtualenv`, which can be used to handle per project requirements of dependent packages.

Comment: Pip may also work when the packages are installed by other tools.

Comment: so u mean it will get all the list of things installed either by pip , easy install , rpm or tar.gz

Comment: Apparently it finds out the installed packages from the shell environment variable $PYTHONPATH that you can set in your shell’s startup file – eg. .bashrc for Bash or .zshrc or .zshenv for Zsh.

There is also PYTHONSTARTUP env variable where you can set Python specific stuff.

Comment: Be sure to include your package manager installed Python’s site-packages/ dir before the system provided Python, if on Mac OS X. The $PYTHONPATH syntax is the same as for $PATH – separated by colons.

Comment: You can also do `pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name` to install into different lib. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/pip-how-do-i-install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory

Comment: i got the list of installed modules but how will install all on other computer provided i installed python in same folder. i have gone through so much headache by providing various lib path. i don't want to repeat it again

Comment: I think you don't necessarily need to set the paths on the new machine, just do `pip install -r my-reqs.txt`, IF you only have one Python installation. You could set the paths just to be sure, especially, if you later decide to install Python somewhere else.

Comment: in my windows, i have installed PyQt5 and few other mods which are not listed by pip freeze.

Comment: @KumaresanLakshmanan See my other answer for the situation without using Pip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46382325/470560

Answer (score 1):

If you are **not using Pip**, then you should check what packages you have in your global and/or user `site-packages` directories.

The solutions below are from:
[How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory)

**Global** site packages:

```
python -m site
```

or more concisely:

```
python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

**User** site packages:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

The latter do not however show the site-packages of the current **virtual environment** – use `distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()` for that:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib;
print get_python_lib()"
```

**Note!**
You can not just copy over the packages that have C++-extensions or other compiled binaries in them. These have to be reinstalled on other machines.