# How come python did not refer to this very simple scenario?

Tags: python, maven

How come python did not refer to this so basic scenario?

[handling multiple modules versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570635/how-to-deal-pip-install-multiple-package-versions)

How come i need to deal with it by myself? when in java i have the maven product to do all this work for me???

Comment: This isnt really a question someone can answer for you. Maybe make the question a little more specific.

Comment: Java does not deal with "this basic scenario". Maven is a third-party tool. Feel free to check out other python configuration management tools; if you find them lacking, you are free to enhance them to meet your needs.

Comment: a third party as maven would also help, i found only virtual env but that's basically just like replicating the java sdk for multiple project-packages which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. Like maven, these are third-party projects and not part of the language distribution itself. I have no idea what maven does exactly, so I can't say for sure whether virtualenv is directly equivalent. It's mainly intended for development and testing environments.

Comment: thanks.  i knew of virtualenv, but its parallel to duplicating the java jdk :), which is like a big big hammer for a smaller problem, like i will duplicate my OS for every library version...