# python setup.py change requirements module name

Tags: python, pip

I have a codebase which needs a specific version of a module. I also have another tool which I use, which uses a different version of the module. I am trying to get these two codebases to play well with eachother.

For example:
Codebase A requires foomodule==1.2 and Codebase B requires foomodule==2.0

How do I install Codebase A using pip (so via setup.py) so that it doesn't overwrite foomodule==2.0

setup.py

```
setup_options = dict(
    install_requires=['foomodule==1.2']
```

---

If I go and manually change the name of `foomodule` folder in dist-packages to `foomodule1.2`, I can then solve the problem by replacing all occurrences of 'foomodule' in my codebase. But how do I do this programatically during setup.py?

I could potentially Install foomodule into a different location, rename it, and move it to dist-packages.
Is there a way to install a required package into a custom location?

Perhaps something like:

```
setup_options = dict(
    install_requires=[('foomodule==1.2', location_of_install)]
)

setup(**setup_options)

new_location = os.join(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(), 'foomodule1.2')
shutil.copyfile(location_of_install, new_location)
```

Comment: It looks like the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570635/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package-with-pip: not possible, use virtualenv.