# Interactive labels on nodes using python and networkx

Tags: python, d3.js, networkx, mpld3

I am trying to make a graph using python with networkx which has many nodes that can be interactively investigated. I want to be able to click or hover above a node and reveal a label which is otherwise not shown.

[D3](http://d3js.org/) seems able to do this well, and there are a couple of python implementations

[mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html)

and

[Drew Conway's Networkx fork](https://github.com/drewconway/networkx)

mpld3 works fine for scatter plots but I don't know how to get it to do what I want for a graph...

implementing   [example code](http://drewconway.com/zia/2013/3/26/visualizing-networkx-graphs-in-the-browser-using-d3)  from Drew Conway:

```
import networkx as nx  
from networkx.readwrite import d3_js
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name d3_js
```

This looks like an error which might have resulted if the forked networkx package was not placed in python's system path....However, I checked the sys path contents and found networkx...so I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you have `networkx` installed both as a fork and as a standard package? The fork will need to come first in the python path - but >1 version of a package likely needs special care (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6570635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like mpld3 will work.  You can get the scatter data by calling `draw_networkx_nodes()` which is just a wrapper for `scatter()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

import networkx as nx
G = nx.path_graph(4)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(axisbg='#EEEEEE'))
scatter = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax)

labels = G.nodes()
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(scatter, labels=labels)
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.show()
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/aflaxman/612ba0293714f2e5f3f9).  So cool.  Now if it had the d3js [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) on top of it, that would be really something!