# How can i install two versions of opencv in ubuntu16.04 with python?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, openbr

I want to install two OpenCV versions on my Ubuntu machine. I need the older version for [OpenBR](http://openbiometrics.org/) and, for development i want to work on the latest version which is OpenCV-3.1.0.
I tried making two build folders but ended up with no useful installation. I m using Ubuntu 16.04 system. and I use OpenCV with python.

I have installed OpenCV-3.1.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 from this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/)

Comment: use virtual environment. Create as many virtual environment as you want. Configuration of one environment won't impact other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing multiple versions of a package with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570635/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package-with-pip)

Comment: Yes. i am installing using virtual environment only. The thing is, that one installation works fine. but as soon as i configure the other, both are messed up. I'll try once again though, fresh installation. But i will use  openbr and opencv 3.1 together, so i want in one environment only.

Comment: Why do you need both installation within single virtual environment. Shouldn't you be doing that in different environment?

Comment: I want to use openbr and opencv 3.1 together.  and openbr uses opencv 2.7..