# Different version of Elasticsearch-py lib within Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to get the data from Elasticsearch (ver. 1.7), and post it into Elasticsearch (ver. 5.2) using Elasticsearch-py with 1 Python script.
But the recommended way within official docummentation (https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is:

*Elasticsearch 5.x* for elasticsearch>=5.0.0,<6.0.0

*Elasticsearch 1.x* for elasticsearch>=1.0.0,<2.0.0

The question is how may I install 2 different versions of elasticsearch-py and use those within 1 Python script (I'm using virtualenv)?

---

I've already checked all the questions like:
[Installing multiple versions of a package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570635/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package-with-pip)
, here are some ideas suggested, but is there some better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about that

```
pip install -t old oldelasticsearch
pip install -t new newelasticsearch
```

and then you should be able to import it like this

```
from old import elasticsearch
from new import elasticsearch
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this gives ImportError: No module named <directory where I stored package>

Comment: (venv) magniff@magniffy700:~/workspace/venv $ pip install -t es_new elasticsearch==5.0.0 and then just python -c 'from es_new import elasticsearch as es_new'. Works fine.