# Pycharm install two branch version of the same module

Tags: python, module, pycharm, branch

I am using the *cloudscraper* python library, installed from the *Pycharm UI*.
Therefore, I am using the main version of this package.

I would like to try to use the *dev* version of this package, that can be downloaded through github from the relative branch (https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper/tree/dev). In order to install this dev package, I have to run `python setup.py install`.
Is there a way to keep both versions of this module? How can I install the dev package directly from the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not handle having multiple versions of the same library installed. See for example [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6570635/11384184).
Indeed, the solution is to modify the files for one of the version to give it a different name (for example `cloudscraper-dev`).

Or you could have two different **virtual env**, one for each version, but it requires to switch from one to the other.