# How can I have 2 verions of Gensim for summarization in one Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter, gensim

I want to have 2 versions of **Gensim** for using summarization and keyword function from old **Gensim**.
How can I setup this senario?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a single Jupyter notebook is backed by a single Python interpreter/environment, and popular packages at their 'official' installation paths can only be installed once.

There are a few hackish workarounds suggested in answers like:

[Installing multiple versions of a package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570635/installing-multiple-versions-of-a-package-with-pip)

However, each workaround presents operational problems.

One approach is to install the older package to a non-standard path (directory) that's still found by Python importing logic (controlled by `PYTHONPATH`). For example, put/move the older copy of Gensim to a `gensim_old` package directory. But: this is only likely to work well with very sime (single-`.py`-file) packages.

With any signficant library (like Gensim) which cross-imports a lot of things from its own utility modules, using the *standard* paths, lots of things are likely to break unless you dig into all involved individual files to change their import paths. That's kind of kludgey & hard-to-maintain. (Though, to the extent you're just using one old version, say `gensim-3.8.3` for the removed summarization feature, perhaps it'd be worth fighting through this process once, then keeping the changes around.)

Another approach is to create a totally-separate Python environment with the alternate version, and only use that other environment from the notebook by a system-call – via either something in Python-code like `subprocess.call()`, or the notebook-cell `!` or `!!` magic-escapes to run a shell command. That is, you give up the ability to run individual interactive lines of Python in that alt environment - but could still send it batches of data, and either capture the console output or observe its output files to continue processing in your notebook.

I'd expect this to be a better option – cleaner & more-maintainable – provided that either the old-version-functionality (summarization) or new-version-functionality (whatever else) can be condensed into one (or a few) single-step scripts.

Another option would be to try to completely copy the `gensim.summarization` source code files to some new location inside your own project – performing whatever (few, minor) edits are necessary to ensure it works from the alternate location.

One of the reasons that functionality was removed was that its approach to things like tokenization was not consistent/integrated with other Gensim practices – which actually means it's likely to be a little easier to keep it working (given its use of its own idiosyncratic approaches) separately.

Personally I'd rank these three options desirability as:

- (best) Section off the summarization tasks to be run via subprocess executions in a separate Python environment, which has only the older package installed.
- (maybe ok) Copy the 10 `.py` files that implement the `gensim.summarization' to your own local module. Edit lightly as necessary to ensure they still work. (That should mainly be updating` import` lines, but might reuire a few other adaptations to other Python 3.x/Gensim 4.x changes.)
- (probably too messy) Install the whole old package to a non-standard directory, edit lots of files to ensure anything you're using still works.

Finally, note that the main reason the feature was removed is that it did not offer very impressive or adaptable results. While I've seen some people say it's worked OK for their applications, I've never seen even so much as a demo where its practices/algorithm – which can *only* extract some subset of important sentences, never paraphrase – gave impressive results.

So unless you already know that its approach works well for your needs, don't get your hopes up! Good luck.