# How to make editable install of Python package from vcs into specific directory using pip?

Tags: python, version-control, pip

By default pip installs *editable* packages into `src` subdirectory of the directory where Python is installed.

I'd like to install a package from version control to a directory of my choosing using pip's support for checking out a package from source control, for example:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git@355b97165c#egg=requests-org
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: [PIP: how do I install a python package into a different directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2915471/95735)

Comment: pip does not install in a directory but in multiple directories. Only if you have a pure python implementation (no scripts/data/binaries) you can talk about a directory of your choosing. Use "--install-option='--install-purelib=/your/lib/path'" in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip help install` says:

```
--src=DIR, --source=DIR, --source-dir=DIR, --source-directory=DIR
                      Check out --editable packages into DIR
```

For example:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git@355b97165c#egg=requests-org --source-directory=/tmp
```

Will install the requests source in `/tmp/requests-org`

Comment: Can this be used in `requirements.txt` files as well? I.e. would adding the line `-e git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git#egg=requests-org --src=/tmp`to such a file work?