# How to install virtualenv scripts to /usr/bin

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I install virtualenv with command `sudo /usr/bin/pip-2.6 install virtualenv`

And it says

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Why pip from /usr/bin looks to /usr/local/lib?

I need to install virtualenv scripts directly to /usr/bin, so I write

```
sudo /usr/bin/pip-2.6 install --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/bin" virtualenv
```

But again it responds with

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Adding --upgrade doesn't help.

How can I install virtualenv scripts to /usr/bin ?

Comment: Any reason it HAS to be /usr/bin? Both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin are in $path by default.

Comment: I make a puppet script which installs different python versions and creates virtualenvs. To not install virtualenv everytime it is convenient to use puppet's argument 'creates' which checks existance of a file. So I'd like to assert that /usr/bin/virtualenv-2.6 exists after I install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current issue can you first uninstall virtualenv using pip, and then reinstall using `--script-dir=DIR, -s DIR` as an `--install-option`.

As for your issue running `pip` with extra arguments and install not seeming to do anything, that may be fixed on `develop` branch at https://github.com/pypa/pip if not please file a bug with us on the GitHub issue tracker for pip.

As to why it is behaving like this - the install is based on the python installation not on the location of pip. Pip uses setuptools/distribute under the hood and conforms to the configuration of the python it is running under.

You can see where the version of python you are using installs to by running it - in this case probably `python2.6` and querying the `sys` module.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
>>> sys.exec_prefix
```

See also `distutils.sysconfig`

For more information:

- [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html)
- [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools)
- [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo /usr/bin/pip-2.6 install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/bin" virtualenv
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/pip-how-do-i-install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory)).

Comment: The same result.And I don't need to install it to /usr/bin. I just want to have sciprts there.