# pip install to a local folder

Tags: installation, python-2.7, pip

Is it possible to install packages to any arbitrary folder? e.g. I tried to install a package to a local folder but it throws error, same error comes up with any other package

```
/tmp$  pip install --install-option="--prefix=mypython" IPy
Downloading/unpacking IPy
  Downloading IPy-0.75.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package IPy

Installing collected packages: IPy
  Running setup.py install for IPy

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 250, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1133, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 604, in install
    f = open(os.path.join(egg_info_dir, 'installed-files.txt'), 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mypython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPy-0.75-py2.7.egg-info/installed-files.txt'
```

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/pip-how-do-i-install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory?rq=1) indicate it should be working, so what is wrong here?

Comment: `wsgiref` is a standard library package. Why are you trying to reinstall it?

Comment: :) that was just an example same error comes with any package, e.g. IPy

Comment: I just ran `pip install --install-option="--prefix=/tmp/temp-virtualenv" ipy` and it worked without any error. (`pip` version: 1.1). With `wsgiref` I get errors.

Comment: @PedroRomano thanks, I have also same version of pip, do you get same error for wsgiref?

Comment: Sorry. I don't actually get an error for `wsgiref` if I pass `pip` the `--ignore-installed` switch. `pip install --install-option="--prefix=/tmp/temp-virtualenv" --ignore-installed wsgiref` also works without any errors.

Comment: Found what we are doing different and the solution: `--prefix` must be an absolute path, not a relative one like you have. See new answer (if possible delete the now irrelevant comments from the answer: thanks!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`--prefix=` needs to be an absolute path. Doing:

```
$ pip install --install-option="--prefix=/tmp/mypython" IPy
```

for example, should work without any errors.