# pip to local folder windows

Tags: python, pip

I am new to Python and PIP but versed in NodeJS and NPM.

(Using Win7, and Python 3.5)

I would like to do something similar that I do with NPM for sending a single folder on a USB stick to an offile user.

That is rather than have PIP install the package somewhere where I (I have no idea where it put it) I would like it in a subfolder of the current project folder that I have.

I am working on a Windows 7 box, and this answer really did not seem to tell me my two questions:

[pip install to a local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807969/pip-install-to-a-local-folder)

1. Where does PIP place things
2. How can I consoldate the folders

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you looked into [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks.