# Equivalent from easy_install of --install-dir and --script-dir on PIP

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, easy-install, webfaction

I am trying to install a library that appears to be available on pip but not on easy install, the way to install in my host, which is webfaction would be something like this:

```
  PYTHONPATH=/$HOME/webapps/<app_name>/lib/python2.7/ easy_install-2.7 --install-dir=/$HOME/webapps/<app_name>/lib/python2.7/  --script-dir= /$HOME/webapps/<app_name>/bin/ TwitterAPI
```

what are the alternatives to the options --install-dir (isn't it --target?) and --script-dir in pip?

Answer (score 0):

You question seems to be duplicating the following: [Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)

Good luck to you anyway :-)