# pip install --upgrade pip installs the same version

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

Somehow `pip --upgrade` doesn't upgrade any packages.

I'm on OSX El Capitan (10.11.3) and installed python using `brew install python`

Python: `/usr/local/bin/python@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python`
Pip: `/usr/local/bin/pip@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/pip`

After successful install I run `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Full output:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.0.2
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Why doesn't pip install the new version?

**Update**

I think it has something to do with my `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file which fixes the `DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both` error when running `pip`. [I followed these instructions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md#note-on-pip-install---user)

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257803/distutilsoptionerror-must-supply-either-home-or-prefix-exec-prefix-not-both)

Comment: Had that same issue a little while ago.

Comment: You can try `pip install -U pip` and tell if you get the same output ?

Comment: What's the output of `which pip` ?

Comment: what about `pip install pip==8.1.0` ?

Comment: @Dex'ter: same output

Comment: @Maresh: /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko: same output

Comment: Are you using Linux? I had a problem once where some packages were owned by the OS, and I couldn't upgrade them. I overcome this using virtualenv. Try to install the latest versions of pip in a virtualenv and see what happens

Comment: @TalesPádua I'm using OSX. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting annoyed by things not working I created a new OSX profile. In the new profile everything was working fine so after investigating further I found a file `~/Library/Application\ Support/pip/pip.conf` in my main profile containing:

```
[global]
target=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I don't know how it got there but removing it resolved the issue.

This also resolved the need for the `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
Downloading pip-9.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 335kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
  Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
Successfully installed pip-9.0.3
```