# How to install pymysql module to AWS Lambda using Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, alexa-skills-kit, pymysql

I am building an Amazon Echo skill, and for some reason I cant figure out how to install pymysql on to AWS Lambda to connect the AWS Lambda function to the Amazon RDS (Mysql) Data Base.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This is a possible duplicate of [How to install pymysql on AWS lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538730/how-to-install-pymysql-on-aws-lambda?rq=1)

You need to first create the Lambda function deployment package, and then use the console or the CLI to upload the package. This basically packages up all your non-default libraries - like pymysql. [Creating a Deployment Package (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

For example, to just install and package `pymysql`:

```
pip install pymysql -t /path/to/project-dir
zip -r lambda.zip /path/to/project-dir
```

Then upload `lambda.zip` through the console or AWS CLI.

Comment: Got all of that taken care of, now the issue is that it is timing out without connecting to the RDS database. Some kind of VPC issue. I even added VPC privilege to the role. Now I am not getting any errors but after waiting the request just times out.

Comment: Check out [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html) Since you're behind a VPC, you need to setup not only the Lambda role to use, but also security groups on the Lambda function and RDS instance.