# Installing pip packages in different directory does not work

Tags: python, pip

I want to install a pip package into a different directory, but pip refuses to do so.

```
$ pip install django -t output

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 264, in finalize_options
    "must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both"
DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both
```

Comment: Perhaps duplicates with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257803/distutilsoptionerror-must-supply-either-home-or-prefix-exec-prefix-not-both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** When I wrote this answer [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) was not available. If you having the same problem, I strongly recommend considering using it.

If you have installed Python using `brew` you need to add a setup.cfg file ([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)) in your project-dir with the following content:

```
[install]
prefix=
```

That will resolve the problem. Alternatively, you can use `virtualenv` or even better docker.