# install python package at current directory

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda

I am mac user, used to run pip install with `--user`, but recently after `brew update`, I found there are some strange things, maybe related.

Whatever I tries, the packages are always installed to `~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`

Here are the commands I run.

```
$ python -m site --user-site
~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

$ pip install --user -r requirements.txt

$ PYTHONUSERBASE=. pip install --user -r requirements.txt
```

So what should be the problem?

I used for lambda zip packaging

#### Updates:

If using Mac OS X and you have Python installed using Homebrew (see Homebrew), the accepted command will not work. A simple workaround is to add a `setup.cfg` file in your `/path/to/project-dir` with the following content.

```
[install]
prefix=
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `virtualenv` instead?

Comment: Where would you like the files to be installed to? Isn't `~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` already user specific?

Comment: As I explained, I installed for lambda zip packaging. They need be installed in current directory and zipped in the lambda functions together.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the [target (`t`) flag](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) of `pip install` to specify a target location for installation.

In use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t /path/to/directory
```

to the current directory:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the error I got `DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both` when run your command

Comment: maybe related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257803/distutilsoptionerror-must-supply-either-home-or-prefix-exec-prefix-not-both

Comment: Nice, above url fixes the error `DistutilsOptionError`, I can install package locally now.