# Installing python packages locally doesn't always work

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-docx, python-click, pendulum

I'm creating a python 3.9 program and want to install packages locally. So the way my project is set up is this:

```
__main__.py
test.py
requirements.txt
lib/
    __init__.py
```

In my requirements.txt file I have 3 lines:

```
colorama==0.2.2
click==8.0.3
pendulum==2.1.2
```

Then I run: `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t ./lib`
This installs all the packages and dependencies inside of the lib directory.

Then I import the modules at the top of my test.py file:

```
from lib import colorama
from lib import click
from lib import pendulum
```

In doing some testing, I've found that colorama works fine. I'll use it in a simple test:
`print(colorama.Fore.BLUE + "Hello, World!")`. The text is blue in the console and everything is working.

I then try to use the other packages and I get ModuleNotFoundError exception:
`print(pendulum.now('Europe/Paris'))`

`Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'pendulum'`
This is coming from one of its own files.

The same thing happens when I use Click, but it's a little different. I'll get the same ModuleNotFound exception, but it's for its own dependency on Colorama. I don't think it's related to the fact that I'm also importing Colorama because if I uninstall I get the same error.

I've also tried this with the python-docx package. I added python-docx==0.8.11 to the requirements.txt file, then issued the same command as above to install to my local lib directory. It seems to install fine. I see the docx directory and all its dependencies. Then I import `from lib import docx` then do something simple in test.py:
`doc = docx.Document()`

Then get ModuleNotFound error:   File "C:\Users\name\Development\python\test-local-package\lib\docx_*init*_.py", line 3, in  (Current frame) No Module named 'docx'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding the full path to the "lib" folder to the module search path.  via `sys.path.append(<full path to lib>)`

Comment: Where do I add that? I'm a python noob

Comment: Plus, I want to be able to package this up in a zip file when I'm done, so it should be able to work with the current working directory and not a full path

Comment: `import sys` as line 1 and then `sys.path.append(<full path to lib>)` as line 2 then the remainder of your imports

Comment: The interesting thing is that my IDE shows that the modules exist when I import them from lib

Answer (score 0):

When you put those libraries into your `lib` folder and import them the way you are doing, you're changing their package names. No longer is `colorama` a top-level package, it's now `lib.colorama`. Some libraries might be fine with that, but for others, they expect to be able to import their own code using their normal names. If `colorama.some_submodule` tries to `import colorama`, it will fail.

It's important to realize that a statement like `from lib import colorama` doesn't change how `colorama` can be found everywhere. It only changes the local namespace. The package is still `lib.colorama`, we've just bound it to the name `colorama` in the current module.

As JonSG has suggested in comments, a better solution is to put the `lib` folder into the Python search path so that `import colorama` will find the package with its normal name. Modifying `sys.path` is one way to do that, another is the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (probably not ideal for your current issue, but sometimes useful in other situations).

Comment: That's interesting. I was under the impression that putting the empty __init__.py file in the lib directory would resolves those issues. What I want to do (in the end) is zip the whole directory from the root, then use the zip file like: 'python my_prog.zip' to run the program. So how can I do that so that the packages in lib will work without having to rely on a system path?