# pip doesn't install some packages, but installs others

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Unable to install some packages (e.g. pandas) using pip...

Traceback last call error:

> [root@XXX ~]# pip3 install pandas Collecting pandas
> Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/01/803834bc8a4e708aedebb133095a88a4dad9f45bbaf5ad777d2bea543c7e/pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
> Installing build dependencies ... error [...rest of output omitted...]

pip error:

> Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -m pip install --ignore-installed
> --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-7ze4l_bl --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Cython "numpy==1.9.3;
> python_version=='3.5'" "numpy==1.12.1; python_version=='3.6'"
> "numpy==1.13.1; python_version>='3.7'"" failed with error code 2 in
> None

However, I am able to install other packages...

> [root@XXX ~]# pip3 install antigravity Collecting
> antigravity [omitted]] Successfully uninstalled antigravity-0.1

The two errors may indicate that it is failing since it isn't installing the numpy dependency, however the trackback last call states a DistutilsOptionError.  I don't believe the pip/python versions should be an issue here.

After some research, this stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728772/4682460) states to use a local setup.cfg file, however I'm looking for a permanent fix to this (not a workaround).  Note that python3.4 was not installed via brew (I don't know how it was installed since it predates my employment).

Python version:

> [XXX@XXX ~]$ which python3 /usr/bin/python3
> [XXX@XXX ~]$ python3 --version Python 3.4.9

Pip version:

> [XXX@XXX ~]$ pip -V pip 18.1 from
> /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-18.1-py3.4.egg/pip (python 3.4)
>
> [XXX@XXX ~]$ pip3 -V pip 18.1 from
> /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-18.1-py3.4.egg/pip (python 3.4)
>
> [XXX@XXX ~]$ python3 -m pip -V pip 18.1 from
> /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-18.1-py3.4.egg/pip (python 3.4)

Note that I was hoping to just forget about pip with python3.4 and use 3.7, but pip doesn't even exist for the python3.7 install here....

> [XXX@XXX ~]$ /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip -V
> /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to install python3-pip via yum and I also went ahead and updated pip to version 20.  I can't say for sure if the pip upgrade was what fixed it.