# How do you specify bin directory for pip install with --target option enabled

Tags: python, pip

To give an example, if I run the command

```
sudo pip install gunicorn
```

There's now a file

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
```

and a folder

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn
```

And I can run "gunicorn" from the shell.

However, if I run the command

```
sudo pip install gunicorn --target=~/tmp_directory
```

There's a folder at

```
 ~/tmp_directory/gunicorn
```

However, there is no "bin/gunicorn" anywhere and I cannot run "gunicorn" from the shell.  Looking through the pip documentation I can't find anything for this particular case.  The exact reason for my doing this is to try and setup a custom buildpack on Heroku.

Comment: This seems to be issue. I really like --target option. I created issue on Github, hope it gets some love https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3934

Comment: Edit: Check my answer, second one. You can specify scripts directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `sudo ln -s ~/tmp_directory/gunicorn /usr/bin/gunicorn`.

If I understand your needs correctly, you're suggested to try [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html), a tool to create isolated Python environments. You can install different versions of Python packages for each of your project on the same server. Highly recommended for Python development. I'm using [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), a wrapper to make it a bit easier to use

Comment: I guess I didn't give much context to my problem...in this case the `/usr/` directory is read only so I couldn't write to it, so a path of `bin/gunicorn` doesn't exist anywhere...it doesn't seem to have been created at all.  I got around the problem by specifying `--root=~` instead of using `--target`

Answer (score 19):

I just found it's actually possible to tell 'pip' where to put scripts, data etc.

You can use `--install-option` to pass options to setuptools. So if you want to specify where to put scripts, you can:

```
pip install gunicorn --install-option="--install-scripts=$PWD/bin" -t python_modules/
```

Now you have `gunicorn` command inside `bin/` in current directory and package installed in target dir `python_modules`.

```
bin/gunicorn
```

Comment: [`no such option: --install-option`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11858)

Answer (score 4):

With Python 3.9, `--target` automatically installs executables into subfolder `bin` of the given target directory.

Answer (score 3):

An issue regarding this problem has been created on GitHub: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3934

This is because the `--install-option="--install-scripts=$PWD/bin"` flag, that is necessary, cannot be used with `.whl` files:

```
.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: 
UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
```