# specify location to install new package using pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

How can I specify a location where I can install new package

when I hit

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

it installs it in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

I wanted to the path to be in

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default package_name
```

In your case it will be like ,

```
pip install --target=/usr/local/bin package_name
```

Comment: in my case should it be pip install --target=d:/usr/local/bin/ virtualenv ?

Comment: @user3378649 Yes in your case it will be `pip install --target=/usr/local/bin package_name`

Comment: why u r adding ":$PATH " at the end of the directory ?

Comment: @user3378649 no need of it

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

Or, another option:

```
pip install package_name -t /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: how can I specify the new location (destination). in my case it should be /usr/local/bin