# PIP package install in different directory

Tags: python, pip

I have a router running openwrt. I've installed `python` and `pip` on it.
I only have have about 25mb free memory in the `/` partition however I have a usb flash drive mounted at `/mnt/sad1` with 2gb.

Currently when I install any `pip` package it goes goes in the `/` partition and that makes me run out of space very quickly.
I'm trying to install `flexget` using pip but would like to install everything for that package i.e. all dependencies etc on the usb drive.

How can I make `pip` install `flexget` on the usb partition instead?

EDIT: I was able to workaround it. I used  "easy_install" to install flexget instead of PIP.
First i had to export the new location into Python's path by running:

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/mnt/sda1

Then installed flexget on the USB:

easy_install -d /mnt/sda1/ flexget

I also added the above export command in Openwrt's startup so that path is always there at bootups.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Comment: You can add `--user` to install to your home directory.