# Use Python libraries without installing them

Tags: python-2.7, libraries, python-import

I recently completed a school project in Python, and I used some non-included libraries like `numpy` and `nltk`.

The problem is I am required to demo the projects on school computers (not my own laptop) and the school computers run Python but don't allow me to install any additional packages (so no `pip install numpy`)

Is there any way I can include these libraries on my USB and help Python find them so my program can still run?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by downloading to folders and setting the `PYTHONPATH` before executing.

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Also, to get the dependencies on there in a convenient manner (other than copying files etc.), you can give `pip` install options to specify a prefix while installing. See [Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip) for more details on this.

Comment: This will only work if the OP uses a machine with the same architecture as his school computer. Numpy has C code in it that generates an architecture-specific shared object library. I'm not sure about NLTK but I wouldn't be surprised if it had some too... it's common to include Python C extensions in mathematical processing libraries in order to improve performance.

Comment: Yes, good point. If the architectures don't match then it would be down to setup.py with some prefix setting, probably requiring a bit of scripting. I'm also not sure how well it would work at all on a Windows machine.

Comment: I don't think I have access to `PYTHONPATH`. I'm programming in Windows but the school computer uses CentOS

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` would be set at runtime, but the difference in architecture renders this somewhat moot as @Mike pointed out since there are native dependencies. If they let you use a virtualenv. You could then `pip freeze` and make a requirements file and then `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the virtualenv. You could also make a `setuptools` based project but both of those options don't really fit into the "copy and run" model as some installation is still required, even though it would be isolated (not system-wide). A Docker container would be best if supported (fairly unlikely).