# How to make 'pip install' not uninstall other versions?

Tags: python, pip

I am managing several modules on an HPC, and want to install some requirements for a tool using pip.

I won't use virtualenv because they don't work well with our module system.  I want to install module-local versions of packages and will set `PYTHONPATH` correctly when the module is loaded, and this has worked just fine when the packages I am installing are not also installed in the default python environment.

What I do not want to do is uninstall the default python's versions of packages while I am installing module-local versions.

For example, one package requires `numpy==1.6`, and the default version installed with the python I am using is `1.8.0`.  When I

```sh
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$RE_PYTHON" numpy==1.6
```

where `RE_PYTHON` points to the top of the module-local site-packages directory, `numpy==1.6` installs fine, then pip goes ahead and starts uninstalling `1.8.0` from the tree of the python I am using (why it wants to uninstall a newer version is beyond me but I want to avoid this even when I am doing a local install of e.g. `numpy==1.10.1`).

How can I prevent pip from doing that?  It is really annoying and I have not been able to find a solution that doesn't involve virtualenv.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Comment: Why don't you want to use a virtualenv? Sounds like exactly what that's for.

Comment: I use that trick to install a "local" copy of the package inside my python scripts folder. Then you can "from . import my_local_version" in the script to bypass the computer's local packages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell `pip` to ignore the current installed package by specifying the `-I` option (or `--ignore-installed`). So you should use:

```
PYTHONUSERBASE=$RE_PYTHON pip install -I --user numpy==1.6
```

This is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916320/510937) answer by [Ian Bicking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303070/ian-bicking).

Comment: FYI, I noticed that when using the system pip (v1.1, on an old Debian version) to "upgrade" itself (i.e. install the new version in /usr/local to avoid overwriting system files) it ignores `--ignore-installed` for some reason.  It just insists on trying to uninstall the existing installation.  (I tried `-t /usr/local` and `--install-option="--prefix=/usr/local"`.)