# Packaging python code for distribution on machines without pip

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

Here's the situation:

I have developed some python code, and I have `pip` available on my machine. I pull in some libraries to make the program behave better, do advanced things, have colored output, etc...

Now I need to ship this code to boxes that **do not have pip** and **will not ever have pip**.

In node, it is trivial to achieve this. You can just deploy your `node_modules` folder and the `npm install` step isn't needed.

What's the best practice to do this for Python? The version I am working with is `Python 2.6.8`, and I only need to care about distributing to `Linux` machines.

I've read that it's possible to just freeze the entire project (including the Python interpreter) and just ship a binary. Would like to avoid that if possible, as it seems wasteful to do that in an environment where Python is available on all of your systems.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can create a zip package and install all needed packages locally in your application directory.

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR: That sounds what I'm looking for. can you explain how to do that or point me in the right direction?

Comment: For local install http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip and for zip packaging http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/10/bundling-python-files-into-stand-alone.html.

Comment: That looks like it. Thanks a lot, will experiment and report back.

Comment: And with a ```sys.path.append('vendor/lib64/python2.6/site-packages')``` in the main script, the packages can be read. You mind if I do a writeup with the findings?

Comment: it's a good idea. :)