# How do I install a python package to /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install a python package on my ubuntu.I am trying to install it through a setup script which i had written.The setup.py script looks like this:

```
    from setuptools import setup

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'pyduino',
    description = 'PyDuino project aims to make python interactive with hardware particularly arduino.',
    url = '###',
    keywords = 'python arduino',
    author = '###',
    author_email = '###',
    version = '0.0.0',
    license = 'GNU',
    packages = ['pyduino'],
    install_requires = ['pyserial'],
    classifiers = [

        # How mature is this project? Common values are
        #   3 - Alpha
        #   4 - Beta
        #   5 - Production/Stable
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools', 
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    ],
    scripts=['pyduino/pyduino.py'],
)
```

Package installs in /usr/local/bin directory.But when I am importing the modules outside the /usr/local/bin,import error occurs.I tried changing path to /usr/local/bin and it works perfectly and import error doesn't occur.How can I install the package so that I can import the modules in any directory? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure the package is installed in `/usr/local/bin`? What command are you using to install?

Comment: @LaurIvan Yes,I am sure.When I set the path to `/usr/local/bin` import error doesn't occur and I can import the modules

Comment: @LaurIvan I am using `sudo python setup.py install` to install the packages

Answer (score 2):

Try install your packages with pip using this

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

as described here [Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip) 
and i'll suggest to read what are 1. pip  2. virtualenv

Good luck :)

EDIT: i found the package is installed with pip like:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local/bin" pyduino_mk
```

Comment: I am installing the package with setup.py.So,my command to install is `python setup.py install` and not with pip.I think your answer is suitable for packages which are to be installed with pip.Any suggestions how to do it manually?

Comment: Now i read the question more carefully and it seems you just have a environmental variable problem, because /usr/local/bin is not in your $PYTHONPATH. Try to do this - add pemanently /usr/local/bin to your $PYTHONPATH like this:
1. Open your ~/.bashrc file and add this to it 


    export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"


logout, login to load the ~/.bashrc and try to import the package. I've done it myself when i had packages installed outside the default site-package folder. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Yeah,that's what i got to know when i was searching for the answers.So,there is no fix directly?I mean with other ways because I want to distribute this code.

Comment: Well apart from adding additional path to the $PYTHONPATH , i don't see other way how the python executable would know there are packages in /usr/local/bin , so there may be other ways but - why bother :) this seems straightforward

Comment: As I said,I want to distribute the code to people,I don't want to see them facing problems like me.So,that's why I need a simpler way :)

Comment: Hm, i think setuptools default install location is in /usr/local/bin. So there is an option to prefix the install path, and you'll give that prefix path the $PYTHONPATH default in your setup script - e voila ! What do you think ? 
Here how you describe the prefix : there is  package_dir = {'foo': 'lib'} option , you may try to get the $PYTHONPATH var and pass it as argument to that option

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages 
Here it is how you describe the install location. So if you use this in the script you can install it at the default python packages folder - given you have inspected the PYTHONPATH var first. This should work

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're using a `scripts` tag to install your python code. This will put your code in `/usr/local/bin`, which is not in `PYTHONPATH`.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html), you use `scripts` when you want to install executable scripts (stuff you want to call from command line). Otherwise, you need to use `packages`.

My approach would be like this:

- install the `pyduino/pyduino.py` in the library with something like `packages=['pyduino']`
- create a wrapper (shell or python) capable of calling your installed script and install that via `scripts=[...]`

Using the `packages` tag for your module will install it in `/usr/local/lib/python...`, which is in `PYTHONPATH`. This will allow you to import your script with something like `import pyduino.pyduino.*`.

For the wrapper script part:

A best practice is to isolate the code to be executed if the script is triggered from command line in something like:

```
def main():
    # insert your code here
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- Assuming there is a `def main()` as above
- create a directory `scripts` in your tree (at the same level with `setup.py`)
- create a file `scripts/pyduino`
- in `scripts/pyduino`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  from pydiuno.pyduino import main

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```
- add a `scripts = ['scripts/pyduino'] to your setup.py code

Comment: Perfect.But still i didn't get the second part i.e., create a wrapper (shell or python) capable of calling your installed script and install that via scripts=[...]. What should i keep in scripts and what is wrapper?Sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: do you have a `def main()` and a `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120789/discussion-between-laur-ivan-and-abhay-gurrala).