# How to pip install a package to /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python, pip

File structure:

- MYTOOL.sh
- main.py
- setup.py

My goal is to get MYTOOL.sh running when a user types: `$ MYTOOL`.

In my `setup.py` file I have the following:

```
class PostInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        subprocess.call("echo source " + getSetuptoolsScriptDir() + "/MYTOOL.sh > /usr/local/bin/MYTOOL && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/MYTOOL", shell=True)
        install.run(self)

def getSetuptoolsScriptDir():
    dist = Distribution({'cmdclass': {'install': OnlyGetScriptPath}})
    dist.dry_run = True
    dist.parse_config_files()
    command = dist.get_command_obj('install')
    command.ensure_finalized()
    command.run()
    return dist.install_scripts

setuptools.setup(
    # ... other settings ...
    scripts=['MYTOOL.sh'],
    cmdclass={
        'install': PostInstallCommand,
    }
)
```

MYTOOL.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON_VERSION=$(python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[0:1])))')
if [ $PYTHON_VERSION -eq 3 ]
then
    python main.py "$@"
else
    python3 main.py "$@"
fi
```

PS:
I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913502/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-to-usr-local-bin) question but it seems unanswered.

Comment: What is the point of the shell script? You can just call the Python script itself.

Comment: My script only runs with python3. So I want to make sure it is python3.

Comment: You can do that without a shell script..just tell your python script which python to use with the shebang.

Comment: Aha, you have a link or example, please?

Comment: Just like your shebang in the bash script has `#!/path/to/bash` you can put a similar shebang for Python `#!/path/to/python3` at the top of your `main.py`, then if you change permissions so you can run it like you do with your shell script, then you can just `main arg1 arg2 ...` and it will run. Works just the same as a bash script.