# Have pip to check for requirement satisfactions looking into custom directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am using `pip install` with the `--target` option instead of using virtualenvs for particular reasons. However, although I'd expect it to behave similarly to virtualenvs, I have stumbled into a strange problem.

When using `pip install package -t /path/to` a second time, instead of skipping the execution of the package's setup.py with the message `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):...`, pip will still run setup.py (which can take quite a while sometimes). Only after running it, pip detects that the directory already exists.

`Target directory /path/to/package already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.`

Is there any way I can force pip not to run the package's `setup.py` when the package is already installed in the custom directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2916320/1005215

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I tried that myself. Well, if it's the only solution, I guess I'll have to play a little more as I might be doing something wrong...