# Issues installing pywin32 behind proxy

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, setup.py

I am trying to install pywin32 behind a proxy, and therefore I had to use the zip, rather than the .exe file available.  I have down this with other packages and they work fine.

```
PS C:\Users\Michael.Spencer\Downloads\pywin32-221\pywin32-221> py -3 setup3.py build
Converting...
Executing...
Building pywin32 3.6.221.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup3.py", line 16
    exec(str(got))
File "<string>", line 1944, in <module>
File "<string>", line 594, in __init__

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ntpath.py", line 75, in join
   path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I have never come across this issue when downloading packages manually. The only issue I can think of is my machine is 64 bit, and maybe the zip file only contains a 32 bit version?  However from what I've read, that would result in a different errortype. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: If you want to install it, why not try `pip install pypiwin32` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32 , also it would depend on the version of python you have installed i.e for 32 bit python installation, the 32 bit version of pywin32

Comment: I am trying to install on my work computer, where I don't have admin rights to save to Program Files, which is my python36 folder is located.  Is there a way to tell pip where to save the package so that I can choose a folder I do have rights to?

Comment: why not create a virtualenv  or is that not possible?

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I have not been able to find a zip version, which is the only way I know of to install packages behind a proxy.

Comment: You should really use virtualenv and you can always build from source ,https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.8.2, though that comes with its own problems. Use can save elsewhere with pip too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Comment: @wolfsgang I'll give the virtualenv a try because it sounds like a good permanent solutions, but as a temporary solution the link you provided suggesting pip install --target=[path] worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate simpler way to install, just re-iterating from the comments, is instead of building from source would be,

`pip install pypiwin32`

and to install in a different directory, for whatever reason,

`pip install --target=[path] pypiwin32` 
from

[Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)