# How to make pip install in to a custom folder

Tags: python, pip

Every time I run `pip install` on my home laptop `pip` installs it in to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` folder. The same `pip install` command run on another Macbook and `pip` installs it into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` folder asking for the root password and it is highly inconvenient.

Question: What needs to be done in order to configure the second laptop so `pip` installs the modules into the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` folder.

Comment: Why can't you just use a virtualenv?

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` should also be protected against non-administrator writes...

Comment: Did you `brew install python` at some point? `/Library/Python/2.7` is the default, system Python

Comment: Yes, I have run `brew install python` on the second laptop too. But `pip` still installs into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Then your pip isn't the brew installed version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install a Python package into a different directory using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)

Comment: Thanks for the link to another similar post. But I don't want to point `pip` installer with the `--target` flag. I want to make a second laptop to act like the first. I would like to know what setting makes a first laptop guide `pip` installer to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: It's your `PATH` variable. `/usr/bin/pip` is not the same as `/usr/local/bin/pip` and you might just need to run `brew unlink python && brew link python`

Comment: Try `virtualenv`