# Python How to move script from windows to linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, pyinstaller

I created a python script by pycharm (I used several libraries). I want to use this script on a Linux server. 
How to do it? I tried with the PyInstaller but it generates .exe

P.S Linux server is without Internet and PIP.

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT 
I read that is imposible and I should use WINE

Comment: PyInstaller should create a working binary. How are you executing it?

Comment: Could you explain why your Linux server is unable to access the internet? Will you only ever be able to access it physically (ie. not over a network)?

Comment: `pyinstaller name.py` or `pyinstaller --onefile name.py` and try wit `pyinstaller -D -F -n name -c "nam.py"`
Yep, I have access by ssh (root). It is internal server.

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual (but not unheard of) for your Linux server to be without an internet connection. (If you're doing secure batch processing, however, this might make sense.) Installing all of your script's dependant packages onto the server will be a bit tougher without internet access.

You'll need to find a packaged Python release, either in `.rpm` or `.deb` format (depending on your Linux distribution). Alternatively, you can compile it from source by downloading a package [from the Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and following the included compilation instructions.

You'll then probably need to get `pip` to install all of your Python dependencies into an isolated directory on a server which has an internet connection, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404371/1993313).

As for how you get these files onto the server, that will depend on your specific circumstances. If it's connected to an intranet, you could eg. use [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) to get them from another Linux machine over ssh, or if you have physical access to the machine, a USB stick might do the trick. However, given that you've managed to get 'pyinstaller' onto the machine, you may already have this sussed.