# Installed kaggle in the wrong directory

Tags: python, kaggle

The kaggle API documentation (https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) states that one needs python 3 installed to install kaggle. However, when installing kaggle with the command `pip install --user kaggle`, it downloads to the wrong folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` os that when I run `kaggle --version`, I get the error `kaggle: command not found.` How can I install kaggle in my python 3 folder?

Ultimately, I'm trying to use the kaggle API by following the steps on their GitHub post (https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api). They state that if I get the error `kaggle: command not found`, I need to ensure that my python binaries are on the right path. I'm not quite sure what this means, but its definitely what's contributing to my problem.

I've installed kaggle using `pip install kaggle` and `pip install --user kaggle`, but both install to the directory at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

When running `kaggle --version`, I got the command `kaggle: command not found`

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to play around with your system environment variables, then there is a simple workaround for that.

Open your python3 command line, then Use pip from your code to install the required package!

```
import pip

def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('kaggle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `pip3 install xxx` or `python3 -m pip install xxx`.