# How to import two files from different directories?

Tags: python, python-import

Try to run this file:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
```

And this return:

```
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

I have file with only psycopg2 and it is work. And I have another file with only flask and it is work too. But when I try to run file with both imports it crush.
How to fix it (include flask/bin/python and /usr/bin/python, that flask and psycopg2 work toogether)?

Comment: Did you install it?

Comment: If this module is installed, you should cross-check your Python path. If it does not contain then Python won't look for this folder to find the module.

Comment: @Guy, Yes, i have edit question

Comment: What is the output if you print your path with `import sys; print(sys.path)` ? Is there a difference in the output with only psycopg2 ?

Comment: Are you using python3 and venv? Do you have two different python installations? Why are you wrinting another `shebang` line in your file (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`) That doesn't do anything, only the first line will be used.

Comment: @Frieder, I use './myfile.py, and I want that flask and psycopg2 work together

Comment: What is the ouput with `#!flask/bin/python; import sys; print(sys.path)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#! PATH` is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and Unix/Linux use it for path for executor. (`/path/to/script.py` insted of `python /path/to/script.py`)

However, it might help to extend the path in which to look for packages.

Run for your extra enviroment (python bin) this:

```sh
# Example:
python -c "import PACKAGE; print(PACKAGE.__path__)"
# Psycopg2
python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__path__)"
```

Output:

```
['/path/to/some/python/psycopg2']
```

(My output: `/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/free/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2`)

```py
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/some/python')  # Without package name
import psycopg2
```

If you add a path with a package name, you must then be one level down, but beware, `__init__.py` files can edit paths through the "namespace" so it's not ideal. But you only work with the package itself. Without it, you work with packages that are available in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have <strike>probably</strike> two different python installations running.

One in `[some path]/flask/bin/python` and one in `/usr/bin/python`. The modules are installed in different environments so you can not use them together.

To fix this install flask module in your 'main' python installation or install psycopg2 in your flask environment.

Comment: Should I install psycopg2 into flask/bin? How to do it? flask/bin/ have file named 'python'. If i install psycopg2 into flask/bin i remove last file 'python'?

Comment: I suggest using pip with `--prefix` to install psycopg2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a package module.
In terminal execute:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

more information in [PyPi - PSYCOPG2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)

Comment: I have it.
I have file with only psycopg2 and it is work. And I have another file with only flask and it is work too. But when I try to run file with both imports it crush.

Comment: You only have it locally, with your project there is a python installation shipped, which is used, but doesn't have the global python modules.