# how include a python package in my current project direct under linux?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package

I'm working at a project on my linux platform. Now I need some lib to install in my project directory, is there a way to do that ?
If I use pip, it installs the lib under ~/.local/lib, also I cannot install it system-wide because that package doesn't exist in my distro environment.

Comment: this should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404371/6885968

Comment: yeah! thanks very muuch!