# Install python package to python distribution of salome_meca on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, pip

I am having problems with installing a python package (pandas) on Ubuntu 18.04 to a specific Python (3.6.5) distribution in Salome_meca located in:
`/home/username/salome_meca/V2019.0.3_universal/prerequisites/Python-365/lib/python3.6/os.py`

if I run:
`sudo python3.6 -m pip install --install-option="--prefix=/home/username/salome_meca/V2019.0.3_universal/prerequisites/Pandas-120" pandas`

It raises an error:
`Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

And I cannot import this module as the python (3.6.5) distribution in Salome_meca cannot find it, when I run the code in the Salome_meca invornment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by firstly input in terminal `./salome shell` and then `pip3 install pandas` and this installed pandas under the python distribution within salome_meca. The only problem is that it was not installed in the correct folder (but works anyway). Probably one should set also the target dir, and then the command should be: `pip3 install pandas --target=/home/lskrinjar/salome_meca/V2019.0.3_universal/prerequisites/Pandas-115`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the -t (target switch) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install -t =/home/username/salome_meca/V2019.0.3_universal/prerequisites/Pandas-120
```

Comment: Thanks, but returns: 'The directory '/home/sername/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/username/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")'

Comment: And if I add also H to the command: sudo -H python3.6 -m pip3 install pandas -t=/home/username/salome_meca/V2019.0.3_universal/prerequisites/Pandas-120
It does not install to the specified directory. Any ideas?

Comment: Add write access for your current user to the directory