# EROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: python

I was trying to install opencv using pip install opencv-python  But got the error Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device. Does anyone know how I could solve this error?

[image]

Comment: hello there you can see ths post it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip