# How to make pip install download a python package (torch) to a specified directory?

Tags: python, pip, download, torch

I'd like to specify which directory pip install downloads the file to because I'm getting this error when installing torch:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[...]
RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.
Command: "/home/.../bin/python3" -m pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
Error code: 1
```

So I tried `"/media/.../python3" -m pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118 -t "/directory/"` but it still downloads to the root drive of my Debian11/KDE machine. Didn't find the solution in the pip documentation. How can I change where it downloads to?

This package has a size of multiple GBs, has really nobody thought of enabling users to specify where it should be downloaded to? Or is using a symbolic link for the cache dir the only way to do this?

Comment: `--target` is about the installation directory. For downloads you might want to check [caching settings](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/). Maybe you need to set the `cache-dir` configuration setting somewhere (maybe through `pip.conf` or an environment variable, see [pip configuration doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/)).

Comment: Can't one set the cache directory for individual downloads?

Comment: I do not know, maybe, it depends... If you use an environment variable combined with `--no-deps`, it might do what you need, something like: `PIP_CACHE_DIR=/some/directory python -m pip install --no-deps torch` (completely untested by me, I recommend you check the docs and experiment). -- But I agree that it should be possible to select options for single dependencies: https://discuss.python.org/t/proposal-overrides-for-installers/23666

Answer (score -2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404371/21545421), you need to use `--target` (`-t`) *before* the module name. So your new command becomes

```
"/media/.../python3" -m pip install -t "/directory/" torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

Comment: I don't see where that answers says it needs to before the module name. It did not work and still downloads to the root partition of Debian.

Comment: It was the example they gave, and was a logical step, hence the advice.