# How to install pip into a tmp directory?

Tags: python, pip, libreoffice

How to install pip into a tmp directory?

I want to install pip into a tmp directory, install a few packages to a custom directory, then remove the tmp directory.

I am creating an extension for LibreOffice that automatically installs `pip` via `get-pip.py` if it is not installed and then installs the extensions required packages.
I have this working for Windows and Linux (LibreOffice sudo install).

On Linux LibreOffice Flatpak it seems it is not possible to automatically install pip using `get-pip.py` and it seems that pip is not available otherwise.

I am working out a work around. My thinking is if I can get access to a pip installer then I can then install packages to a custom directory in the extensions sub-directory. Then it should be a simple matter to add the sub-directory to the python `sys.path`.

So this leaves me trying to figure out how to install pip into a tmp directory when the extension is installed into a flatpak version of LibreOffice.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual environment maybe? https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Seconding @ElmoVanKielmo - this sounds like a job for `venv`

Comment: Have a look at [Install a Python package into a different directory using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip)

Comment: A virtual environment is no possible. The code is run in a Flatpak version of LibreOffice. Creation of a virtual environment would not be possible in that environment.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I currently have no access to pip to instruct it to install into a different directory. My first hurdle is to install pip into a tmp directory in a flatpak environment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with in code is to download the Wheel file for pip from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). The wheel file is just a zip file so it can be extracted by unzipping it.

The [InstallPipFromWheel](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python-libreoffice-pip/blob/0c1e373a4aba3e34fa827a4ee93c25baf5430070/oxt/___lo_pip___/install/install_pip_from_wheel.py#L13C7-L13C26) class does the work and is part of my [Python LibreOffice Pip Extension Template](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python-libreoffice-pip) project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--root` option of the built-in [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#command-line-interface) module to install `pip` in an alternative root directory:

```
python -m ensurepip --root /tmp
```

And then add the `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` directory in it to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so that the interpreter can find `pip` as a module when you run it with `python -m pip`.